# JQuery UI Reactive Sliders (Updating Multiple Sliders Simultaneously on Slider Change)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to update multiple sliders simultaneously on the `slide` and `change` events for sliders in JQuery UI.

I have code like the following:

```
$(function() {
    var totalSliders = 0;
    $(".slider").each(function() {
        var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        $(this).empty().slider({
            value: value,
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            slide: updateSliders,
            change: updateSliders
        });
        totalSliders++;
    });

    function updateSliders(event, ui) {
        var activeSlider = this;
        $(".slider").slider("value", $(activeSlider).slider("value"));
    };

    $("#update").click(function() {
        $(".slider").slider("value", 10);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This succeeds in turning everything with a class of `slider` into a slider. However, whenever I move a slider, I get the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've also tried the following implementation of `updateSliders`:

```
function updateSliders(event, ui) {
    var activeSlider = this;
    $(".slider").not(activeSlider).slider("value", $(activeSlider).slider("value"));
};
```

The following implementation of `updateSliders(event, ui)` works fine:

```
function updateSliders(event, ui) {
    console.log($(this).slider("value"));
};
```

**Question:**
How can I avoid the maximum call stack size error? I want all the sliders to update simultaneously.

**Edit:**
I only have three elements on the page with a class of `slider`, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying that handler:

```
function updateSliders(event, ui) {
    if (!event.originalEvent) return;
    var activeSlider = this;
    $(".slider").slider("value", $(activeSlider).slider("value"));
};
```

Now that might cause some *other* problems with your code, I guess, but by checking for a null "originalEvent" property you can tell when your "change" handler is being called due to a programmatic update. That will keep all the updates that you're doing from that very function from causing a firestorm of further changes.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/tRBJU/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: Very nice! I've also found that `$(activeSlider).slider("value")` can be optimized to `ui.value`.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain `!event.originalEvent`? It seems counter intuitive, like saying "if this isn't the original event, then return."

Comment: The "event" object you get from jQuery isn't the "real" event object that the browser creates when an event happens.  It's a wrapper. The "originalEvent" property of that wrapper object gives you access to the native browser event.  If there is no such native event, then you can infer that the "change" handler is being called because of a programmatic update to the slider (i.e., that something set the "value" of the slider with JavaScript).  Make sense?